# Firebase - Can't authenticate with Google sign in

Tags: firebase, google-authentication

I'm playing around with Firebase and I'm trying to get authenticated through Google sign in. I created a firebase project and in sign-in methods, I enabled the Google provider.

Then in my index.html I have this which was mostly generated by firebase init. I added the button in there.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script src="signin.js"></script>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button id="signin">Sign in</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in my signin.js I handle the login

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyC8bHVEtWDcTLJ0b8UOOZ5ClCV1tobqm5w",
        authDomain: "second-d10d4.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://second-d10d4.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "second-d10d4",
        storageBucket: "second-d10d4.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "912088308787",
        appId: "1:912088308787:web:24c9fa6af5dd0771"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    let signinbutton = document.getElementById("signin");
    signinbutton.addEventListener("click", signin);            
  });

  function signin(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(result => {
        console.log("auth success")
        console.log(result)

        var token = result.credential.accessToken

        var user = result.user

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("auth error")

        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        var email = error.email;

        var credential = error.credential;

    })
}
```

After deploying, when I visit the site and try to sign in I receive this error.

```
403. That’s an error.

Error: restricted_client

Application: project-912088308787

You can email the developer of this application at: unconfiguredapp@google.com

This app is not yet configured to make OAuth requests. To do that, set up the app’s OAuth consent screen in the Google Cloud Console.

Learn more

Request Details
response_type=code
client_id=912088308787-potc94v4vl23tscu3gm9pnqu282s52nl.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=https://second-d10d4.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
state=AMbdmDnNM2kSjUeMO4KsxjdWqODEehA03g2bOBE5ZMEgzwCFXx5_n81fN_IKs52mn6P9bWpzMGF0ja9gDSyA39vx5ukZo_bY6UBitPUkFTKQvK3hSYxYyrjCxW4mJ3F5076yhktxbVchOAkMtKCl7vyh2pX4SjBV2YjvP-_CL8l9y-RWaegyO7_qq7qcxXsjVe8SKziqRV_AjMt7I9GZTVfaLovBfz-KkLwG1CSGdvfXs8XZImuDz6KR9sri-QlcDFthhxih0EOi9fJt10oNYEvBNtn5Y_54sQcMVKanlnIWiltG-KJyjY_0pwy6HyhPBDdDGKUe5g
scope=openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

Edit:
Problem solved. Solution proposed by user: Vanduc1102 fixed it.
Set the support email in firebase project settings
[image]
Edit 31/07/2019:
If you still have issues after inserting the support email: On the displayed 403 Error page, clicking "Learn More" takes you to the GCP "OAuth Consent Screen"
From there you will see two fields "Support email" and "Application Logo". For the Application Logo any icon/image can be used to identify the app and for the support email, should be the email used in the firebase console. Once Application Logo is uploaded and Support Email field is filled, save the changes and Google Authentication should now work with your app.

Comment: The answers are certainly relevant to your question - google owns firebase and it is part of the same suite of the google cloud platform console. Just follow the directions in the answers below to finish the setup and you will be fine.

Comment: I recommend trying this tutorial - it has you setup and use firebase with google cloud platform console and vue: https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase

Comment: If you solved your problem another way then please answer your own question on stackoverflow so other users can benefit from it.

Comment: firebase settings are part of the google cloud platform...IDK why you are so adamant that firebase isn't part of the Google cloud platform... It helps typically to be friendly and accept that people are trying to help you on Stack Overflow... :D

Comment: I read what you posted and those appeared to be valid answers to your question. Not every answer posted will be a valid answer, no need to get angry at people for trying to help.

Comment: I cannot speak to why your question was downvoted, it happens, don't get offended, it isn't even necessarily related to what you believe. Take a deep breath and move on, you got the answer you needed from SO. Hopefully this post helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you set up your OAuth Consent Screen?

If not, you'll need to set it up here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Are you getting this message when you try to authenticate through Google sign in? If so, click the "Learn More" link and it should take you to the OAuth Consent Screen setup page as well.

[image]

Be sure to select an email address (I've forgotten that before and it resulted in this error!)

Finally, if you've done all that and you are still seeing the error message, you may want to open up an incognito browser and/or clear your cache.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, I suggest working through the first seven lessons of this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/  --- this will take you through the process step-by-step, which should help you become more familiar with firebase authentication

Comment: If you can make a minor edit to this answer so I can upvote you, that would be great. Thank you. Your bottom post as well :)

Answer (score 24):

I got the issue while following the tutorial: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-setup-firebase-authentication-with-react-in-5-minutes-maybe-10-bb8bb53e8834

I fixed the issue by correcting the **support email** field, it was blank

[image]

Comment: Also note After clicking "Learn More" on the 403 Error page, in the OAuth consent Screen, the application logo and support email fields both need to be filled. Application logo can be any image used to represent the project.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up OAuth 2.0
To use OAuth 2.0 in your application, you need an OAuth 2.0 client ID, which your application uses when requesting an OAuth 2.0 access token.

To create an OAuth 2.0 client ID in the console:

Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
If the APIs & services page isn't already open, open the console left side menu and select APIs & services.
On the left, click Credentials.
Click New Credentials, then select OAuth client ID.
Note: If you're unsure whether OAuth 2.0 is appropriate for your project, select Help me choose and follow the instructions to pick the right credentials.

Select the appropriate application type for your project and enter any additional information required. Application types are described in more detail in the following sections.
If this is your first time creating a client ID, you can also configure your consent screen by clicking Consent Screen. (The following procedure explains how to set up the Consent screen.) You won't be prompted to configure the consent screen after you do it the first time.
Click Create client ID

Comment: Firebase is owned by the Google Cloud Platform. Google Authentication is a GCP service. You need to go there to enable it.

Comment: Go here --> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Comment: You may simply need to set up your OAuth consent screen here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Comment: @Nina glad you got it figured out!